# SQL Outputing Column names based on subquery

Tags: sql, calculated-columns

I want to get the column names for the output of a query by doing:

```
SELECT      queuename
FROM        queue
WHERE     queue.queuename LIKE 'CLIENT VIP%' and queue.status = 1
```

And for the rows I want to indicate the distinct users of each queue:

```
FROM         queue INNER JOIN
                      queue_users ON queue.queueid = queue_users.queueid INNER JOIN
                      users ON queue_users.userid = users.userid
WHERE     queue.queuename LIKE 'CLIENT VIP%' and queue.status = 1 and userstatus = 1
```

So for the out put I would have something like:

```
User    QueueA  QueueB  QueueC
----------------------------------
Bob     Bob     Null    Bob
Joe     Joe     Joe     Joe
Bill    Bill    Null    Null
```

Is this even POSSIBLE in SQL, or do I need to process the output of the query in something else?

**NOTE:** *I can't assume I know the queuenames for the output.*

Comment: It's probably possible in sql server which has a pivot function.  However, if you were going to display it in something else anyway, it might be simpler to do the processing at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your RDMBS, here's one appoach using `MAX` and `CASE`:

```
SELECT users.userid, 
    users.user,
    MAX(CASE WHEN queue.id = 'A' Then users.user END) QueueA,
    MAX(CASE WHEN queue.id = 'B' Then users.user END) QueueB,
    MAX(CASE WHEN queue.id = 'C' Then users.user END) QueueC
FROM         queue INNER JOIN
                      queue_users ON queue.queueid = queue_users.queueid INNER JOIN
                      users ON queue_users.userid = users.userid
WHERE     queue.queuename LIKE 'Otsuka VIP%' and queue.status = 1 and userstatus = 1
GROUP BY users.userid
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a617e/3)

You may need to update some of your field names -- I guessed at a few.  The above SQL Fiddle should get you in the right direction though.

***--EDIT--***

Given your most recent edit, if you don't know the queuenames (meaning you don't know how many columns you want to return), then this is starting to sound more like a presentation issue than a database issue.  You could perhaps use dynamic SQL to achieve your results, but again, you're better off doing that on the UI side than the DAL side.

Comment: This method works, but I was hoping for something that would scale well when the number of queues went higher.  (After looking at the data, I need to switch to Users across instead of Queues. Usernames are short and queue names are too long!)

Comment: Forgive my lack of understanding. But what does the MAX statment do in this example?

Comment: @NoMoreZealots -- It's a way to perform a PIVOT table.  If you're using Oracle or SQL Server, you could look into actually using the PIVOT() command.  Best of luck.